# Primes for which 2 is a primitive root

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, terminology, primitive-roots

I am writing a paper in which I keep referring to primes p for which 2 is a primitive root mod p and so I want to give a name for these primes.  Is there a name for these primes in the literature already? I could not find one. Thank you.

Comment: "2-advanced?" I'm pretty sure "advanced" isn't already a technical term.

Comment: I've read a lot of papers on this topic, and I don't know of any standard terminology more concise than "primes for which $2$ is a primitive root". The closest possibility I know of would be "Artin prime (for $2$)", because of Artin's conjecture that there are infinitely many such primes.

Comment: Based on what Greg M. has written above, there is room for a more concise term. However *2-advanced* is too arbitrary, it does not associate with the topic (most everything can be *advanced*). Thus I would suggest: *2-rooted prime*. E.g. prime 5 is 2-rooted.

Comment: @WlodzimierzHolsztynski, my rationale was that a prime is advanced relative to 2 if 2 is primitive relative to it. But maybe that's a stretch.

Comment: I think I like the term "2-rooted."  Thank you all for your comments.